# Not getting the URL parameters through a web activity in IBM WCS

Tags: java, request, websphere-commerce

I created a Web activity in IBM commerce for checking the current page URL parameters. I am appending the URL parameters through javascript. But the web activity is not getting my URL parameter if my URL pattern is https://www.abcd.com But the activity is working fine if the URL is https://www.abcd.com/en/store

When I append, the URL param in first case is https://www.abcd.com/?key=value ----- web activity not working
second case https://www.abcd.com/en/store/?key=value -------activity is working. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are required, language id and store is.  Those en/store are the seo tokens for those values, without them WCS doesn't know where to route the request, and your web activity is set up to a specific store.